# NoClassDefFoundError org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode only with run-app

Tags: grails

I have a strange situation in a grails application. My application use spring-security-ui, and I'm using the class *org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode*.
The weird stuff is that, when I use this class the application throw an Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode
```

but If I try to open the **grails shell** and write a script that import that class, it works.
If I generate the **war** and deploy it on Tomcat the application works fine.
It is just the *run-app* that won't work.
Which can be the cause of this error?
Thanks

UPDATE:
Now I have the same situation when I try to register a user, or do a login...

```
2012-07-10 12:24:40,835  ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - NoClassDefFoundError occurred when processing request: [GET] /myapplication/dashboard
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.
Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LoginController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [LoginController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:909)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [LoginController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
   ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
   ... 3 more
```

But if I put this piece of code in a controller it works:

```
println org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.class
```

Some suggest?

MORE INFO:

```
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
blueprint           1.0.2            --  Blueprint CSS framework
burning-image       0.6.0            --  Burning Image
ckeditor            3.6.2.1          --  CKeditor plugin
constraints         0.6.0            --  Custom domain constraints plugin
famfamfam           1.0.1            --  Silk icons from famfamfam.com
hibernate           2.0.1            --  Hibernate for Grails
invoicer            0.1              --  Invoicer Plugin
jdbc-pool           0.3              --  Tomcat JDBC Pool plugin
jquery              1.7.1            --  JQuery for Grails
jquery-ui           1.8.15           --  jQuery UI resources
jquery-validation   1.7.3            --  JQuery Validation Plugin
jquery-validation-ui1.2.3            --  JQuery Validation UI Plugin - Client Side Validation without writing JavaScript
lesscss-resources   1.3.0.3          --  Less CSS Resources
mail                1.0              --  Provides Mail support to a running Grails application
quartz              0.4.2            --  This plugin adds Quartz job scheduling features to Grails application.
rendering           0.4.3            --  Grails Rendering
resources           1.1.6            --  Resources
spring-security-core1.2.7.2          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
spring-security-ui  0.2              --  Spring Security UI
tomcat              2.0.1            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

I have the classes to manage spring security users, roles and controllers in a plugin developed from another company.
But it is strange because the *NoClassDefFoundError* is for SpringSecurityUtils class, that if I try to import it inside a controller it works fine...

Comment: well, I think that means that class doesn't get imported. Are you sure that the config is ok?

Comment: another weird stuff is that if I generate the WAR and deploy it on my local Tomcat, the application works fine...it is just the run-app command that doesn't work

Comment: before you try "run-app" command again, I propose using "grails clean" command to clean up all the project.

Comment: check if deleting the contents from .grails/<grails-version>/<your-project-folder> and restarting the application works

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? Which plugins/Versions do you use in your application? Could you identify the code which throws the exception? I would like to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the library is not included in your development environment:
You can add the library to your development environment simply by adding the dependency in the BuildConfig.groovy file :

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        runtime 'apacheexec:commons-exec:1.1' // this is the external library that I added which is the apache commons exec.
    }
```

for more info go to this page : 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies

I hope it helps